# VMWare vSphere Powercli Get-Stat does not work on some host

Tags: powershell, powercli, esx

I'm trying to do some capacity planning on my VMWare host and would like to extract cpu/memory stats for each host.

I'm able to run a command such like this:

```
PowerCLI C:\> Get-VMHost -Name "192.168.1.14" |Get-Stat -Stat mem.usage.average -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)
```

and it displays the stats.

But then I pick another host, such as `192.168.1.15` and it doesn't work, ending with this error:

```
Get-Stat : 2015-06-23 10:56:45    Get-Stat        Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:42
+ Get-VMHost -Name "192.168.1.15" |Get-Stat <<<<  -Stat mem.usage.average -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Stat], VimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetViStats
```

The command `Get-VMHost -Name "192.168.1.15"` works.

Any idea?

```
PowerCli 5.0.1
VMWare ESX 5.0 Update 3
vCenter 5.0.0 Build 1300600
```

Comment: Does `Get-VMHost -Name "192.168.1.14" | Get-Stat -Memory | ? { $_.metricid -like "mem.usage.average" }` output that statistic?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is the Date object being passed to the cmdlet `Get-Stat`. From the error it appears to be treating the date as an object? According to the [documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41/html/Get-Stat.html) that supported input for `-Start` and `-Finish` is "dd/mm/yyyy".

Try this instead

```
Get-Stat -Stat mem.usage.average -Start ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") -Finish (Get-Date -Format "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

For `-Start` we need to do date calculation *before* we convert to string.`.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` is one method of doing it. Since you are using today for the `-Finish` we can just use `-Format` from `Get-Date` to get the string without complication.